# Как перезапустить named из php скрипта

Tags: php, centos

Есть VPS с centos 7 с root доступом. Необходимо время от времени из php скрипта выполнять там команду:

```
systemctl reload name.service
```

Какой php код для этого лучше всего использовать?

Answer (score 1):

Для выполнения команды можно использовать php-функцию **[exec](http://www.php.su/exec())**. Правда, могут быть вопросы с правами доступа, так как для выполнения указанной Вами команды понадобятся права root. А какими правами обладает Ваш скрипт - неизвестно. Скорее всего он запущен от имени апача. Поэтому, как варианты, это либо использовать утилиту **[sudo](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sudo&category=8&russian=0)**, либо же запускать сам php через suexec (но тогда php будет работать не от имени апача, а от указанного).